# How do I make bg image of header 100% of browser height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to expand the background image of the header to 100% of browser height but it doesn't work. The bg image is just a small bar although it is a big wallpaper, do you see my mistake?

```
<head>                                             
    <meta charset="UTF-8">                         
    <title>TEXT</title>                            
    <meta name="description" content="text">  
    <meta name="keywords" content="text" >    
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">    

</head>

<body>                                             
    <header>                                       
        <h1>TEXT <br> <span>TEXT</span></h1>      
    </header>

    <section>                                      
        <article>
        <p>TEXT</p>
        <img src="images/spachtel1.jpg"><br>
        <img src="images/spachtel1.jpg"><br><br>
        </article>
    </section>

    <footer>                                          
        <h3>text<br>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Here's the CSS file:

```
    @font-face {                                                    /* ERSTENS LADE font family rein*/
    font-family: 'alex_brushregular';
    src: url('../css/alexbrush-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../css/alexbrush-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../css/alexbrush-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../css/alexbrush-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../css/alexbrush-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../css/alexbrush-regular-webfont.svg#alex_brushregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

    html {
    font-size: 1rem;
}

    html {
    height: 100%;
}

    body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;                                      
    padding: 0;                                     
}

    h1 {                                                          /
    font-family: 'alex_brushregular', 'sans-serif';
}

    section p {                                                     
    font-weight: 100;                                          
    font-size: 1.13rem;                                        
    font-style: italic;
}

    span.by {                                                       
    color: red;
}

    section a {
    color: #eda318;
    text-decoration: none;                                  
    font-style: normal;
}

    section a:hover {                               
    text-decoration: underline;
}

    header {
    background-image: url('../images/bgheader1.jpg');
    background-position: 50% 50%;                     
    background-size: cover;                         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because your background image is set only to affect your header. Try making it affect your body.

Comment: First answer on Stackoverflow! Awesome.  One recommendation is to improve your answer by providing a code sample of what you mean by your recommendation.  e.g. in the CSS code replace the `header{...}` with `body{
background-image: url('../images/bgheader1.jpg'); 
background-position: 50% 50%;                     
background-size: cover;                         
}` if you want the image covered across the entire web page.

Comment: that would cause the picture being over the whole page. What I want is the picture to cover the whole "landing page" and when I scroll then the rest of the body should appear (without the background image). that means I think I should put the image to the header?but what is wrong then... example: http://domanistudios.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the background image styling to the `<BODY>` tag instead of the `<HEADER>` tag like this:

```
body {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/');
  background-position: 50% 50%;                     
  background-size: cover;                         
}
```

Comment: that would cause the picture being over the whole page. What I want is the picture to cover the whole "landing page" and when I scroll then the rest of the body should appear (without the background image). that means I think I should put the image to the header?but what is wrong then... example: domanistudios.com

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:
I had to write

```
height: 100%;
```

to the header of the CSS file.